# How can I make a property transient in Spring Data and Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a property in my entity that I don't want to persist in Elasticsearch, since it's a "calculated" property, not a field, so I added `@Transient` (from spring data):

```
public class Vehicle {

    //more stuff

    @Transient
    public String getType() {
        if (something) {
            return "A";
        }
        return "B";
    }

}
```

But I'm getting a mapping error (it's defined as strict and it doesn't know the field "type").

I know I could use `@JsonIgnore`, but I need to return an instance of Vehicle back to the user via Json REST API and that property must be included.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to return an instance of Vehicle back to the user via Json REST
>   API and that property must be included

You are on the rigth way! You can ignore whatever you want by a `@JsonIgnore` as well as you can add any JSON property by a `@JsonProperty` annotation

In this case you can do something like this:

```
@JsonProperty("type")
public String getTypeForMyBusinesLogic() {
  return getType();
 //or whatever you want to return
}
```